# Failed to open session error

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to use ansible to connect to my switches and just do a show version. For some reason when i run the ansible playbook i keep getting the error "Failed to open session", i don't know why i keep getting it. I am able to ssh directly to the box with no issues.

```
[Ansible.cfg]
enable_task_debugger=True
hostfile=inventory
transport=paramiko
host_key_checking=False

[inventory/hosts]
127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local
[routers]
192.168.10.1


[test.yaml]
---
- hosts: routers
  gather_facts: true
  connection: paramiko

 tasks:
  - name: show run
    ios_command:
      commands:
      - show version
```

then i try to run it like this

```
ansible-playbook -vvv -i inventory test.yaml -u username -k
```

And then this is the last line of the error

```
EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
fatal: [192.168.10.1]: UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "Failed to open session",
"unreachable": true
}
```

Anisble version is 2.4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Please use::

```
  connection: local
```

Answer (score 0):

change `- hosts: routers` to `- hosts: localhost`